# What did i miss in this code? Shopping Cart JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, shopping-cart

So , i'm trying to make a shopping cart. When i press the "Minus" or "Plus" i get this error on console:

> Cannot read property 'textContent' of null
> at HTMLElement.

When i click for remove i get this:

> Cannot read property 'inCart' of undefined
> at HTMLDivElement.

The code is this:

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('.add-cart');

let products = [
  {
    name: 'Kristina Dam Oak Table With White Marble Top',
    tag: 'product1',
    price: 799.55,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Activate Facial Mask and Charcoal Soap',
    tag: 'product3',
    price: 129.55,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Cocktail Table Walnut | YES',
    tag: 'product4',
    price: 299.99,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Hay - About A Lounge Chair AAL 93',
    tag: 'product5',
    price: 659.55,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'TORY DESK CALENDAR',
    tag: 'product6',
    price: 410.99,
    inCart: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'CH445 Wing Chair on SUITE NY',
    tag: 'product7',
    price: 330.55,
    inCart: 0,
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
  carts[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    cartNumbers(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i]);
  });
}

function onLoadCartNumbers() {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
  if (productNumbers) {
    document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers;
  }
}

function cartNumbers(product, action) {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
  productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);

  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  if (action) {
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers - 1);
    document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers - 1;
    console.log('action running');
  } else if (productNumbers) {
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1);
    document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = productNumbers + 1;
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', 1);
    document.querySelector('.cart span').textContent = 1;
  }
  setItems(product);
}

function setItems(product) {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
  productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  if (cartItems != null) {
    let currentProduct = product.tag;

    if (cartItems[currentProduct] == undefined) {
      cartItems = {
        ...cartItems,
        [currentProduct]: product,
      };
    }
    cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;
  } else {
    product.inCart = 1;
    cartItems = {
      [product.tag]: product,
    };
  }

  localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}

function totalCost(product, action) {
  let cart = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

  if (action) {
    cart = parseInt(cart);

    localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cart - product.price);
  } else if (cart != null) {
    cart = parseInt(cart);
    localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cart + product.price);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('totalCost', product.price);
  }
}

function displayCart() {
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  let cart = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
  cart = parseInt(cart);

  let productContainer = document.querySelector('.products');

  if (cartItems && productContainer) {
    productContainer.innerHTML = '';
    Object.values(cartItems).map((item, index) => {
      productContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="product"><img src="src/img/${
        item.tag
      }.png" />
      
      <div class=product-info>
              <span>${item.name}</span>
              <span>$${item.price}</span>
      </div>
         
        <div class="quantity">
          <i class="decrease fas fa-minus" ></i>
          <span>${item.inCart}</span>
          <i class="increase fas fa-plus" ></i>
                 
          </div>
          <div class="total">$${item.inCart * item.price}</div>
          <div class="remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
          </div>
          `;
    });

    document.getElementById('total-price').textContent = '$ ' + cart;
    document.querySelector('.cart-align span').textContent = '$ ' + cart;
    deleteButtons();
    manageQuantity();
  }
}

function manageQuantity() {
  let decreaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.decrease');
  let increaseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.increase');
  let currentQuantity = 0;
  let currentProduct = '';
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);

  for (let i = 0; i < increaseButtons.length; i++) {
    decreaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(cartItems);
      currentQuantity = decreaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span')
        .textContent;
      console.log(currentQuantity);
      currentProduct = decreaseButtons[
        i
      ].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling
        .querySelector('span')
        .textContent.toLocaleLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g, '')
        .trim();
      console.log(currentProduct);

      if (cartItems[currentProduct].inCart > 1) {
        cartItems[currentProduct].inCart -= 1;
        cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct], 'decrease');
        totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct], 'decrease');
        localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
        displayCart();
      }
    });

    increaseButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(cartItems);
      currentQuantity = increaseButtons[i].parentElement.querySelector('span')
        .textContent;
      console.log(currentQuantity);
      currentProduct = increaseButtons[
        i
      ].parentElement.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling
        .querySelector('span')
        .textContent.toLocaleLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g, '')
        .trim();
      console.log(currentProduct);

      cartItems[currentProduct].inCart += 1;
      cartNumbers(cartItems[currentProduct]);
      totalCost(cartItems[currentProduct]);
      localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
      displayCart();
    });
  }
}

function deleteButtons() {
  let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
  let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
  let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
  cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
  let productName;
  console.log(cartItems);

  for (let i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      productName = deleteButtons[i].parentElement.textContent
        .toLocaleLowerCase()
        .replace(/ /g, '')
        .trim();

      localStorage.setItem(
        'cartNumbers',
        productNumbers - cartItems[productName].inCart
      );
      localStorage.setItem(
        'totalCost',
        cartCost - cartItems[productName].price * cartItems[productName].inCart
      );

      delete cartItems[productName];
      localStorage.setItem('productsInCart', JSON.stringify(cartItems));

      displayCart();
      onLoadCartNumbers();
    });
  }
}

onLoadCartNumbers();
displayCart();
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You posted a lot of code here. It doesn't appear that all of this is necessary to reproduce the issue. That means your question isn't following the "Minimal" principle from the documentation that Rojo linked to. You should work to find the absolute least amount of code that you can that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: Which line is throwing this? Wherever it is, the querySelector you're using doesn't exist, hence `null`.